# How do I move my button to be next to the textbox?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button, textbox

I have a textbox component here in which I imported a "+" button called Add. The Add button component is found in this code in these specific tags.

```
<Add clickEvent={this.addTextBox}>+</Add>
```

**The + button is coming up directly on top of the textbox but I want it to the left (and some padding)**

Here is all of the code for textbox.jsx (I am using React.js)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Add from "./add/add";

class Textbox extends Component {
state = {
boxtext: "",
addBox: [],
};

handleChange = () => {
// The line below creates a copy of the state, using the spread operator
let fields = { ...this.state.boxtext };
fields = fields + "+";
this.setState({ fields });
};

//Handle box addition click
addTextBox = () => {
const boxAdded = [...this.state.addBox];
boxAdded.push(1);
this.setState({
  addBox: boxAdded,
});
};

render() {
return (
  <div
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      left: "50%",
      top: "17%",
      transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    }}
    className="form-group"
  >
    <label for="exampleLogicSymbol">Logic Operator</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      className="form-control"
      id="exampleInputLogic"
      aria-describedby="logicHelp"
      placeholder="enter formula"
      onChange={this.props.handleInput}
      value={this.props.content}
    />

    <Add clickEvent={this.addTextBox}>+</Add>
    {this.state.addBox.map(() => {
      return (
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id="exampleInputLogic"
          aria-describedby="logicHelp"
          placeholder="ENTER"
        />
        //clickevent is made up name (property)
      );
    })}
  </div>
 );
}
}

export default Textbox;
```

Code for Add component (add.jsx)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Add extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
return (
  <div
    className="App"
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      left: "30%",
      top: "19%",
      transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    }}
  >
    <button
      onClick={this.props.clickEvent}
      className={"btn btn-success btn-sm m-2 p-1 container"}
    >
      +
    </button>
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Add;
```

Comment: By simply replacing your `Add` component by a simple button, the button appears next to the textbox. You probably have some code that is making it `display: block`, either a `<div>` wrapping your `Add` component or some css inside. If you want more help please provide the code of your `Add` component.

Comment: I gave the code for the add component. I do not want to replace it with a simple button, how would I change it now?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the css of your Add component, make it `display: 'inline-block'` and remove the rest.

Here is the [repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-cttbmk?file=add.js) and here is the code:

Add component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Add extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
return (
  <div
    className="App"
    style={{
      display: 'inline-block',
    }}
  >
    <button
      onClick={this.props.clickEvent}
      className={"btn btn-success btn-sm m-2 p-1 container"}
    >
      +
    </button>
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Add;
```

Textbox component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Add from "./add";

class Textbox extends Component {
  state = {
    boxtext: "",
    addBox: []
  };

  handleChange = () => {
    // The line below creates a copy of the state, using the spread operator
    let fields = { ...this.state.boxtext };
    fields = fields + "+";
    this.setState({ fields });
  };

  //Handle box addition click
  addTextBox = () => {
    const boxAdded = [...this.state.addBox];
    boxAdded.push(1);
    this.setState({
      addBox: boxAdded
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: "50%",
          top: "17%",
          transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
        }}
        className="form-group"
      >
        <label for="exampleLogicSymbol">Logic Operator</label>
        <div>
          <Add clickEvent={this.addTextBox}>+</Add>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            id="exampleInputLogic"
            aria-describedby="logicHelp"
            placeholder="enter formula"
            onChange={this.props.handleInput}
            value={this.props.content}
          />
        </div>

        {this.state.addBox.map(() => {
          return (
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="exampleInputLogic"
              aria-describedby="logicHelp"
              placeholder="ENTER"
            />
            //clickevent is made up name (property)
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Textbox;
```

App component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Textbox from './textbox';
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Textbox />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

For the Textbox, I only put the Add component above your input so it appears on the left as you asked in your question. I also wrapped both with a div to display them correctly.

About your css, you should think about externalize it in a .css/.scss file, it will make your code cleaner

Comment: Thank you for the proposition but not really interested, but you can still ask all of your questions here, the community is great and will help you. I'm not the only one and if your questions are the same level as this one, you will get answers really fast ;) If you need a quick review I can still have a look on it if you have a repo to provide